# flask celery get task real time task status

Tags: asynchronous, flask, celery, django-celery, celery-task

all

I am using flask and I am searching for a way to display eventually in a table the celery job status. I have come up with a solution that is only working half way. I have mongodb running as my backend_result I thought I could just query the db for the status. Unfortunately it this never tells of pending task only jobs that were successful or failed, so if there were to be a long running task you would not know that the job was pending.

Is there any solution to get all the real time task status.

```
@app.route('/process/')
def process():

    result = add.delay()

    return 'async request sent'

@app.route('/job_status')
def job_status():

    db_coll = 'flask_app_job_results'

    job_status = (mongo.db[db_coll].find({}, {'status':1, '_id':1})).sort('date',pymongo.ASCENDING)

    job_status_list = []
    for r in job_status:
        try:
            job_status_list.append(r['status'])
        except:
            app.logger.info('status key value not found in mongoDB')

    app.logger.info('in job status the jobs are {}'.format(job_status_list))


    return str(job_status_list)

@celery.task(name='app.add')
def add():
    time.sleep(60)
    num = 5 + 5
```